# does video.js provide support for blob file coming from Autodesk BIM360 doc?

Tags: html5-video, video.js, autodesk-bim360

I am using video.js library for my video player. I have provider Autodesk bim360 doc, my video file is there.

I am getting url like - 
blob:http://sample-client-for-test-plan.localtest.me:3000/11c90362-8e46-4195-94c8-940d56c4aa42

from provider but that is not supported in video player.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code -

```js
function bim360_player(res, callbackFn) {
  console.log(res.video_url)
  callbackFn();

  var player = videojs('#video_viewer' );

  videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options) {
    options.headers = options.headers || {}
    options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + res.auth_token;
    return options;
  };

  player.ready(function() {
    this.src({
      src: res.video_url,
      withCredentials: true,
      type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    })
    this.play();
  });
  
 }
```

Comment: If you can share an example webpage where you're trying this that would be helpful. However, I doubt video.js and html5 video support an autodesk file. You will probably need to transcode it into another format.

Comment: @heff, i updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to get a signed URL in BIM360.